# HtmlElements finds 3 elements instead of only one in block when searching with XPath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, htmlelements

I have a block:

```
@Block(@FindBy(xpath = "//tr[contains(@class,'bg-success')]"))
public class ShareContentRowBlock extends HtmlElement {

   @FindBy(xpath = "//h3[@class='fileName']/span/a")
   private TextBlock contentNameText;

   public String getContentName() {
       return contentNameText.getText();
   }

   .... // some other elements and methods
}
```

I described a page:

```
public class DocumentLibraryPage extends SitePage {

    private List<ShareContentRowBlock> shareContentRowBlocks;

    .....

    public ShareContentRowBlock getShareContentRowBlock(String name){
        for (ShareContentRowBlock conentRowBlock: shareContentRowBlocks){
            if(name.equals(conentRowBlock.getContentName())){
                return conentRowBlock;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I try to get element, it returns not exactly element that I want to see.

I have html with elements tree:

```
   html
       h3.fileName
         span 
             a
       h3.fileName
         span 
             a
       table.bg-success
         h3.fileName
             span 
                 a
```

I want to get element `<a>` inside table, but it returns all 3 `<a>` elements.
When i try to debug it really finds all `<a>` elements with ignoring parent block xpath.

What wrong with it? Am I need to change selectors, or describe block in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting xpath locator with "**//**" means absolute block position. In order to make relative search you should start it with "**.**":

```
@Block(@FindBy(xpath = "//tr[contains(@class,'bg-success')]"))
public class ShareContentRowBlock extends HtmlElement {

   @FindBy(xpath = ".//h3[@class='fileName']/span/a")
   private TextBlock contentNameText;

   public String getContentName() {
       return contentNameText.getText();
   }

   .... // some other elements and methods
}
```