# List of block, annotated by FindAll, searched many elements of first item

Tags: webdriver, findall, thucydides, htmlelements

There is block, where BaseBlock inherits from HtmlElement

```
@FindBy(css = "article.item")
public class FlatCatalogItem extends BaseBlock<FlatCatalogItem> {}
```

There is other block, that include FlatCatalogItem

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='objects']")
public class SearchResultObjectTabsBlock extends BaseBlock<SearchResultObjectTabsBlock>
{
    @FindAll(@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'js-tabs tabs')]/div"))
    public List<ButtonWithText> tabHeaders;

    @FindAll(@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='realty-result-content-list']/article"))
    public List<FlatCatalogItem> searchedItems;
}
```

and there is page, that inherits from BlockPageObject (htmlelements class for integration tith thucydides)

```
@DefaultUrl("/realty")
public class FlatCatalogBasePage extends SiteBasePage<FlatCatalogBasePage>
{
    public SearchResultObjectTabsBlock searchResultTabs;
}
```

Problem, when call SearchResultObjectTabsBlock.searchedItems, return 30 objects (true count) of same elements (first finded element) (all 30 objects - first finded element). When call SearchResultObjectTabsBlock.tabHeaders, returned true count of different elements (this is true behavior)

Why in first scenario returned 30 same objects?

Comment: please look an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404866/htmlelements-finds-3-elements-instead-of-only-one-in-block-when-searching-with-x

Comment: thank you, but it's different problems. I searched correct count of correct elements, but his content reference to first element (

Comment: Ok, i got the problem, but can't get why it happens. Try remove @FindAll annotation at first (it useless in your example) and tell me if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, problem with relative xpath))